# Using filter with includes doesn't filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to filter out an array of objects which are `classes` within an object called studentUserProfile. When I run the code below, filter doesn't filter out anything.

object `studentUserProfile`;

```
{  
   "_id":"ZgfgbGpMxF5T6pNT8",
   "firstName":"Angela",
   "classes":[  
      {  
         "classId":"3x8cNzzr4DQ4PioM7"
      },
      {  
         "classId":"oehC4pWbFLDAjbzvt"
      }
   ]
}
```

`filterIds = ["oehC4pWbFLDAjbzvt", "3x8cNzzr4DQ4PioM7"];`

**Code**

```
let studentUserProfiles = this.props.studentUserProfiles.map((studentUserProfile) => {
  studentUserProfile.classes = studentUserProfile.classes.filter(myClass => filterIds.includes(myClass.classId));
  return studentUserProfile;
});
```

Comment: Mutating studentUserProfiles in a map is probably what is causing the issue.

Comment: That could explain it. How am I suppose to do it?

Comment: I tried your code and it works, probably you should declare a new variable to it? `const result = this.props.studentUserProfiles...`

Comment: remove map and check with `studentUserProfile.classes.filter(...other code)`

Comment: @bp123 what is your expected o/p?

Comment: Ok, the problem appears to occur when the filterIds array is built the second time around. As in I click filter by Id `oehC4pWbFLDAjbzvt` then I click filter by `3x8cNzzr4DQ4PioM7` a second time. It appears as the `this.props. studentUserProfile` has been permanently changed.

Comment: Can some explain how `studentUserProfile.classes = studentUserProfile.classes.filter(myClass => filterIds.includes(myClass.classId));` can affect things outside of the `sudentUserProfile` map.

Comment: As your line `studentUserProfile.classes = studentUserProfile.classes.filter(myClass => filterIds.includes(myClass.classId));`. It is an object and it will always update value to all its references. So when you assign new value to `studentUserProfile.classes` as `oehC4pWbFLDAjbzvt ` on first time it will update existing object also and now `studentUserProfile.classes` have value as`[{ "classId":"3x8cNzzr4DQ4PioM7"}]`

Answer (score 0):

FYI -So the problem was to do with how I was returning `studentUserProfile`.

```
const studentUserProfiles = this.props.studentUserProfiles.map((studentUserProfile) => {
  const classes = studentUserProfile.classes.filter(myClass => filterIds.includes(myClass.classId));
  if (classes.length >= 1) {
    return {
      ...studentUserProfile,
      classes,
    };
  }
  return null;
}).filter(studentUserProfile => studentUserProfile !== null);
```